# add dynamic elements to xml on button click android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add elements dynamically in to the existing xml layout on a button click. Based on the number of times a user clicks on a button, that many items should be added in to the existing xml. I think using the layout inflater is a good technique, but I am not able to do it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! Here is my code:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_id">
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_item_id">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java file:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item, mainLayout,false);

    mainLayout.addView(view);

    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context c=getApplicationContext();
            TextView tvv=new TextView(c);
            tvv.setText("textview");
            mainLayout.addView(tvv);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the error or post the stacktrace from Logcat. Your app should crash and you haven't mentioned that also.

Comment: I'm sorry. The error is that,  the application runs and the view with the button gets displayed. However, when the button is clicked, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button belongs to `layout_item.xml`.

So change this

```
 Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

To

```
 Button b=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

You should use Activity Context

```
Context c=ActivityName.this;
```

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Fragment fr; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item, mainLayout,false);

        mainLayout.addView(view);
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        Button b=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context c=MainActivity.this;
                TextView tvv=new TextView(c);
                tvv.setText("textview");
                ll.addView(tvv);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

layout_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_item_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

snap

[image]

Comment: Thank you Raghunandan for that answer. However, when the button is clicked, nothing happens. No text view gets added. It was the same output as before. Can you please tell me how to correct this?

Comment: @userstack first you need to make the changes as said then specify what doe snot work

Comment: I made the modifications. After that, the result is that, nothing happens when button is cicked

Comment: @userstack views are not added to existing xml. its added to the screen. You cannot change the existing xml layout at runtime

Comment: Ohk. So is there no way to add elements dynamically to the exisitng xml?

Comment: @userstack you can check the example. If you are trying to re-use layouts there is a `include` tag available. what you are doing is simply not possible

Comment: Thank you Raghunandan! This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you